# Facebook Debugger Tool: Can't figure out 404 error

Tags: html, facebook, social-networking

I posted a new article on my website and for whatever reason the Facebook Debugger tool is giving me an error of `Bad Response Code    URL returned a bad HTTP response code.`

Here's the URL to the Facebook debugger with the URL in question:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.winetracker.co%2Fblog%2Fhow-to-host-a-virtual-wine-tasting%2F

And here's the page url in question:
https://winetracker.co/blog/the-ultimate-visual-guide-to-champagne-and-sparkling-wine/

All my meta tags appear to be in order. The URL works great on other social sites.

Here are the meta tags I'm using:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">      
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>How to Host a Virtual Wine Tasting</title>
    <meta property="og:type" content="article">
    <meta name="description" content="Everything you want to know about how to host a virtual wine tasting event.">
    <meta property="og:title" content="How to Host a Virtual Wine Tasting">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Everything you want to know about how to host a virtual wine tasting event.">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://winetrackerco.imgix.net/virtual-wine-tasting-event.jpg">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://winetracker.co/blog/how-to-host-a-virutal-wine-tasting/">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Winetracker.co">
    <meta name="twitter:image:alt" content="Title screen for How to Host a Virtual Wine Tasting?">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="376948262489475">
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@winetrackerco">
```

WTF Facebook? All the other articles on my site work fine, but this one doesn't.
What can I take a look at to fix this?

Comment: Maybe spell “virutal” in the `og:url` value correctly instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(embarassed)... Thanks to @cbroe for the eagle-eye find that I have a typo in my `<meta property="og:url...` where I mispelled virtual as virutal. I updated that meta tag url and it works fine now.